# Check if audio file contains DRM

Tags: macos, drm, itunes-store

How can I verify if a file is protected by DRM?

On OS X, by command line or by other methods.

Comment: Not being familiar with OSX, is there not a properties section for the file, probably in an Advanced area which states it is protected?

Comment: You're right, it's in the "More Info" of the file info panel in the Finder.

Comment: Added as answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/questions/367182/check-if-audio-file-contains-drm#comment521520_367268) noted in comments, you can use the `mdls` command to get the file metadata. The `kMDItemKind` field should hold the info you’re looking for.

```
$ mdls plain-mp3.mp3 | grep kMDItemKind
kMDItemKind                     = "MP3 audio"

$ mdls protected-aac.m4p | grep kMDItemKind
kMDItemKind                    = "protected MPEG-4 audio"

$ mdls unprotected-aac.m4a | grep kMDItemKind
MDItemKind                    = "Apple MPEG-4 audio"
```

(Note also the different extensions, `.m4a` vs. `.m4p`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
mplayer $filename
```

If you hear sound, there are no (effective) restrictions.

`mplayer` can be obtained from [this place](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/).

Answer (score 1):

In the finder, just Get Info on your file, and look at the *More Info* area.  Within this area of the info panel it should state whether the file is protected or not.  Here's an example of a protected AAC file:

[image: Part of info panel]

Comment: Probably also in the Spotlight metadata (`mdls` on the command line)